# Mask integer in Read-Only input field in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, mask, input-field

I have 2 pages.In first page i will fill my mobile number.Then,navigating to the second page I will show the mobile number in read only.In that i need to show the number like xxxxxx1234. If user clicks the edit button then,it should show all the numbers like 8790561234.

I couldn't get the masking for read only field.?Any suggestions??

Comment: what you had tried so far??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With slice and replace, you can achieve what you want:

```
var orig = scope.ngModel;
    var edited = orig;
    scope.ngModel = edited.slice(4).replace(/\d/g, 'x') + edited.slice(-4);
```

Check out [this similar Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/f9oYZkqClSqe3plzDH44?p=preview).